# What does the "Use for Development" button in Xcode Organizer do to an iOS device?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xcode-organizer

When selecting an iOS device and clicking the "Use for Development" button in Xcode organizer, what does it change on the device (iPhone or iPad)?

Are there any debugging symbols installed or some sort of profilers or loggers?

Does this mode affect device performance or battery life while being "used for development"?

Comment: Anybody know if there's a way to return a device to be a non-"Use for Development" device? (Short of hard reset of course...)

Comment: @AndyWeinstein Only know that the Mac can disable it "Disable Developer Mode", searched for the same button for iOS Devices

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From my experience, the practical consequences of turning on a device for development are an increase of levels of logged data and access to these logs. (I'm not sure if logs are activated for all apps or just those you develop yourself.)

This extra logging activity might have a storage impact and an impact on energy consumed too but as you're most of the time plugged in a machine running XCode when you test the applications you develop, I never saw any impact on the battery life when I switched back to be a regular user of my device (as opposed to a developer user).

Comment: What about application testers who are not developers themselves?  Would there be any impact for a regular iPhone or iPad user who has their device in development mode because their developer friend installed an app on their device from Xcode?

Comment: I can't tell precisely but non-developers from my team who activated the "use for development" never complained about it. You can also use services such as TestFlight to install apps for beta-test without registering devices as "used for development".

Answer (score 9):

It installs a development profile certificate on your device. Code signed by these certificate will be accepted to run on the device.

Answer (score 3):

Regarding your question, Does this mode affect device performance or battery life while being "used for development"?

No, there is no additional drain on the battery.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Development mode enabled on your iPhone you can access Settings > Developer menu e.g for emulating network conditions http://natashatherobot.com/simulate-bad-network-ios-simulator/ (amazing feature).

Comment: Seriously?! 3 years after the question was asked and 2.5 years since it was answered?!